# Can use I stopPropagation of mouseHover like onMouseEnter in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mousehover

I use onMouseEnter on a parent div. when I mouse hover on a child element the parent mouseHover is fired fired and I want to stop it. I used e.stopPropagation() but also the parent mouseHover fired. When I mouseOver on the child element, The parent mousehover is fired. I prevent this parent's mouseHover Event. **onMouseEnter={(e)=> e.stopPropagation()}** I am using this on the child element to stop the parent mouseHover. But still parent mouseHover is fired.

How can I stop Event Bubbleing for onMouseEnter ???

Or, **is it possible to stop Event Bubbleing for mouseHove like onMouseEnter?**

[image: There is function and state]

[image: Using onMouseEnter on JSX]

```html
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Slider.css'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide} from 'swiper/react';
import SwiperCore, {Navigation, Pagination} from 'swiper';

const Slider = ({works}) => {

  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false)
  const [cssProperty, setCssProperty] = useState({});
  const mouseHover = (e) => {
    const {width, left, top, bottom} = e.target.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()
    setCssProperty({width, left, top, bottom, opacity:1})
    console.log(left)
  }

  const mouseLeave = (e) => {
    setIsShown(false)
    setCssProperty({opacity:0, mouseLeaveClass:"mouseLeaveClass"})
  }

    return (
        <div>
         
            <Swiper> 
            
           
              {
                works.map((work,index) => (
                  <SwiperSlide key={`slide-${index}`} tag="li" style={{listStyle:"none"}} className=""  >  
                    
                    <div  onMouseEnter={(e)=> mouseHover(e)}  onMouseLeave={() => mouseLeave()}  className="job-item"  >
                    <div className="job-info" style={{marginBottom:"5px", margin: "0 10px"}}>
                      <div className="job-dates" >

                          <span className="single-job-date">
                            <span className="job-date-items">
                              {work?.month && <span className="month" style={{color: "#fff", fontSize:"1rem", opacity:".7"}} onMouseEnter={e=>e.stopPropagation()}  > {work?.month} </span>}
                              {work?.startDate && <span className="date" style={{color: "#fff", fontSize:"32px"}}  > {work?.startDate} </span>} <br/>
                            </span>
                          </span>
                          
                           
                        
                        <span className="end-single-job-date" >
                          <span className="job-date-items" style={{marginRight:"15px"}}>
                          {work?.endMonth && <span className="month" style={{color: "#fff", fontSize:"1rem",  opacity: ".7"}} onMouseEnter={(e)=> e.stopPropagation()}> {work?.endMonth} </span>}
                            {work?.endDate && <span className="date" style={{color: "#fff", fontSize:"32px", }} onMouseEnter={(e)=> e.stopPropagation()}> {work?.endDate} </span>} <br/>
                          </span>
                        </span>
                            
                      </div>

                      <div class="job__title" style={{height: "110px", fontSize:"23px",color: "white !important", fontWeight:"500", transition:"all .5s", position:"relative"}}>
                        {work.company} <br/>
                        <span style={{fontSize:"16px",}}> {work.position} </span>

                       
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    </div>
                  </SwiperSlide>
                ) )
              }
              
              
            </Swiper>
            
        </div>
    );
};

export default Slider;
```

Comment: Did you try to flag it with state? 'isMouseHover' or something?

Comment: Share the code too.

Comment: yes, set on the state with a function  -OrAssayag

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly paste the codes instead of attaching a screenshot. This allows the users here to copy and paste to help you debug your codes.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime just to confirm, as you are not adding any behaviour on the child element on mouseEnter, just add the below styles to all elements where pointer events are not needed.

```
pointer: none;
```

Ofcourse other solution is to check the target of the event and if it's not the one intended, just skip the rest part of the logic.

Comment: yes, it stops onMouse Event and onClick event also. and The css Property is pointer-events: none; But can I use e.stopPropagation()

Comment: @MainulIslamFaruqi Edits are supposed to improve grammatical mistakes, clarify a post, update as the post ages or add related sources/hyperlinks. They are not to point out technical inaccuracies. If you think the answer is incorrect, please downvote it.